# Axiom of completeness equivalent statements

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen two "different" statements both of which are referred to as the Axiom of Completeness. They are equivalent, but I can not seem to see why they are equivalent. The statements are:

**Axiom of Completeness 1:** Suppose $L, H \subset \mathbb{R}$ where both $L$ and $H$ are non empty and satisfy $\forall l \in L, h \in H, l \le h$. Then, $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall l \in L, h \in H, l \le \alpha \le h$.

**Axiom of Completeness 2:** Every non empty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

From my introductory studies of real analysis, I have been mostly exposed to statement 2. Can someone explain why statement 1 is equivalent to 2?

Comment: shouldn't version 1 not include that $L \cup H$ is all numbers ?

Comment: It is from pg 31 de la Fuente "Mathematical Models" and does not make mention of $L \cup H$.

Comment: I don't really use it anyway. But it's clearly inspired on Dedekind cuts, where this does hold.

Comment: Statement 1 is Dedekind's theorem which is based on the Dedekind's construction of real numbers. And it is generally given with the additional constraint $L\cup H=\mathbb{R} $. This constraint ensures that the $\alpha$ in conclusion is unique. In your version there can be many numbers playing the role of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose version 1 holds.

Let $A$ be a set of reals with an upperbound $u$.
Define

$$L = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \exists a \in A: x < a\}$$ and

$$H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \forall a \in A: a \le x\}$$

It is clear that $L$ and $H$ cover all reals and the condition on $L$ and $H$ is satisfied. Also $H$ is non-empty as $u \in H$.
Then the promised $\alpha$ with $L \le \alpha \le H$ is equal to $\sup(A)$.

If version 2 is satified, we just take $\alpha = \sup(L)$.

Comment: Thanks, very concise explanation, really makes it clear now!

Comment: @user56031 sure, fill in the details, if you like, as an exercise, I wanted to give the main idea.